# Ubuntu 12.10 Virtual Host

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

Hello I've tried to make a virtual host for localhost on apache 2 but did not succeed

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName portal
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/portal/public
    <Directory /var/www/portal/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in `/etc/hosts` the line `127.0.0.1 portal`

And to make it work for:

**Apache 2.2**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

**Apache 2.4**

```
Require all granted
Satisfy Any
```